# Making indices stackable

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

One thing I have always disliked about the TeX syntax is that double superscripts or subscripts yield an error; I would have found it more natural if they were simply stacked instead. So for fun, I decided to try and change that, so that e.g. `a^2^3` became equivalent to `a^{23}`. Only thing is, it does not seem to work e.g. with primes or commands which expand to `^{-1}`, see below. So the following MWE will yield an error. Can this be fixed somehow? (I assume not.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`^=\active
\catcode`_=\active

\makeatletter
\let\old@sp=\sp
\let\old@sb=\sb
\NewDocumentCommand{\@stack@index}{mme{^_}}
{%
    \IfValueTF{#3}{%
        \IfValueTF{#4}{%
            \@stack@index{#1#3}{#2#4}%
        }%
        {%
            \@stack@index{#1#3}{#2}%
        }%
    }%
    {%
        \IfValueTF{#4}{%
            \@stack@index{#1}{#2#4}%
        }%
        {%
            \old@sp{#1}\old@sb{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}

\def^#1{\@stack@index{#1}{}}
\def\sp#1{\@stack@index{#1}{}}
\def_#1{\@stack@index{}{#1}}
\def\sb#1{\@stack@index{}{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\( x^2^3_2_{222}^{423} \)

\( x'^{-1} \)

\newcommand\inv{^{-1}}

\( x'\inv \)

\( x^2\inv \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Other than fun, I don't think that `a^2^3` is sensible input.

Comment: @egreg Of course not; that’s just a test case. The real purpose is to make things like `a'^2`, `a'\inv`, `\pi_1\pushforward`, etc. possible. (I know I could make these few things work on a case-by-case basis by modifying the `\@stack@index` construction with arguments of type `s{\inv}` or `s{\pushforward}`, but I was looking for a general, out-of-the-box solution like above.)

Comment: @egreg That being said, my math is typed in `semantex`, where such issues never arise. I was just curious if this kind of thing was possible at all.

Comment: @egreg Anyway, I reckon (from your silence) that it’s simply not possible?

Comment: of course it's possible:-) just promise @egreg a +50 bonus and he'll do anything:-)  harder is to keep `x^\frac12` and `x^\mathrm{y}` working (personally I don't care if they break but a lot of people will)

Comment: @Gaussler I don't understand your comment about making `a'^2` possible, the default definition of `'` goes to some effort to make that work in both plain and latex

Comment: what do you want `x^2^3_2_{222}^{423}` to typeset as? `x^{23423}_{2222}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlise Indeed, I want `x^2^3_2_{222}^{423}` to be `x^{23423}_{2222}`. Oh, I actually did not notice that `a'^2` was possible. Anyway, that’s not the important thing; the important thing is stuff like `a'\inv` and `\pi_1\pushforward`, where `\pushforward` is defined to expand to `_{*}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not know that egreg cared that much about bonuses. I mean, can’t he already buy a house for the credits he has?

Comment: you could do `a'\inv` and `a'\pushforward`  just with the insertion of an `\expandafter` into the definition of `'` so it sees the `^` in the macro. If that is enough you wouldn't have to touch `^` and `_` at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don’t like throwing `\expandafter`s around :-). Also, it was about `\pi_1\pushforward`, not `a'\pushforward`. :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops, at some point, I updated the question and moved the catcode assignments, but did not notice that this caused the code to break. Now I moved them back, so indeed, the first line `x^2^3_2_{222}^{423}` typesets just fine now.

Comment: @Gaussler No, I'm simply not interested in this.

Comment: @egreg Fine. Then how would *you* make a *practical* macro for pushforwards that works on `\pi_1`?

Comment: What is `\pushforward`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Mathematical sheaf pushforward. Defined to be `#1_{*}`.

Comment: So, should `\pi_1\pushforward` typeset as `\pi_{1*}` or `\pi_{1_{*}}`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The first one. `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use a `tokcycle` pseudoenvironment `\subsup...\endsubsup` to accomplish the goal.  It can range over as much of the document as you like, as long as it does not encase catcode-changing tokens, such as verbatim.

The logic is as follows:

0. The token cycle examines every token in the input stream successively.  In just about every case, it is merely accumulated in the `\cytoks` token list.  However, for tokens that are "characters", it performs the following test:
1. `\testss` initializes and then tests `#1` for scripting catcodes.  If it fails, it executes `#2` (which places the tested token into `\cytoks`).  If it succeeds, it calls...
2. `\accumsup` or `\accumsub` to accumulate the next tokens into `\thesups` or `\thesubs`, respectively.  It then goes to...
3. `\contss` to peek and see if the next token is of scripting  catcode.  If it is, it discards the peeked-at scripting-token and goes back to step 2.  If not, it goes to...
4. `\closess` to set the contents of `\thesups` as a superscript and the contents of `\thesubs` as a subscript (by adding them to `\cytoks`).  It then exits and returns to the token cycle.
5. At the conclusion of the environment, `\cytoks` is typeset.

Note this process only applies to outer nesting of sub/superscripts.  The inner nesting acts in the normal fashion.  In my MWE, for example, I could not use `z_i_j` in place of `z_i` because `z_i` is nested inside the `\sum`'s scripting.  I would have to use the conventional `z_{ij}`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-05-27]
\newcommand\testss[2]{%
  \def\thesups{}%
  \def\thesubs{}%
  \tctestifcatnx ^#1{\accumsup}{%
  \tctestifcatnx _#1{\accumsub}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\contss{%
  \tcpeek\next
  \tctestifcatnx ^\next{\tcpop\discard\accumsup}{%
  \tctestifcatnx _\next{\tcpop\discard\accumsub}{\closess}}% 
}
\newcommand\closess{%
  \ifx\empty\thesups\else
    \addcytoks{^}\groupedcytoks{\addcytoks[1]{\thesups}}\fi
  \ifx\empty\thesubs\else
    \addcytoks{_}\groupedcytoks{\addcytoks[1]{\thesubs}}\fi
}
\newcommand\accumsup{\tcpopappto\thesups\contss}
\newcommand\accumsub{\tcpopappto\thesubs\contss}

\tokcycleenvironment\subsup
{\testss{##1}{\addcytoks{##1}}}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}

\begin{document}
\subsup
\section{No problem}

$\sum_{3\sqrt{z_i}}^4_x^{xy^2}rs$ And now display style
\[
  \sum_{3\sqrt{z_i}}^4_x^{xy^2}rs
\]

\section{Still no problem}

Wow! $\sum_{3\sqrt{z_i}}^4_x^{xy^2}rs$ And again display style
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{3\sqrt{z_i}}^4_x^{xy^2}rs
\end{equation}
\endsubsup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now the above version does *not* intercept macros that expand to a script.  It becomes problematic to try to expand *every* macro encountered, in search of a scripting catcode.

However, if one has a particular macro in mind, whose replacement text is a script, such as `\inv`, defined as `^{-1}`, or `\pushforward`, defined as `_{*}`, then tests can be performed to intercept such macros and substitute their replacement text in the input stream.  Similarly for the special case of the `'` script-prime.

The following MWE required changes to the `\subsup` tokcycle environment as well as the `\contss` macro to execute the additional intercept of the `\inv` and `\pushforward` macros.  The `\contss` macro required changes to intercept the `'` script-prime token.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-05-27]
\newcommand\testss[2]{%
  \def\thesups{}%
  \def\thesubs{}%
  \tctestifcatnx ^#1{\accumsup}{%
  \tctestifcatnx _#1{\accumsub}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\contss{%
  \tcpeek\next
  \ifx\inv\next
    \tcpop\discard\tcpush\inv\contss
  \else
    \ifx'\next
      \tcpop\discard\tcpush{\empty\prime}\accumsup
    \else
      \ifx\pushforward\next
        \tcpop\discard\tcpush\pushforward\contss
      \else
        \tctestifcatnx ^\next{\tcpop\discard\accumsup}{%
        \tctestifcatnx _\next{\tcpop\discard\accumsub}{\closess}}% 
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand\closess{%
  \ifx\empty\thesups\else
    \addcytoks{^}\groupedcytoks{\addcytoks[1]{\thesups}}\fi
  \ifx\empty\thesubs\else
    \addcytoks{_}\groupedcytoks{\addcytoks[1]{\thesubs}}\fi
}
\newcommand\accumsup{\tcpopappto\thesups\contss}
\newcommand\accumsub{\tcpopappto\thesubs\contss}

\tokcycleenvironment\subsup
{\testss{##1}{\addcytoks{##1}}}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\tctestifx{\inv##1}{\tcpush\inv}{%
 \tctestifx{\pushforward##1}{\tcpush\pushforward}{%
 \addcytoks{##1}}}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
\newcommand\inv{^{-1}}
\newcommand\pushforward{_{*}}

\begin{document}
\subsup
\begin{equation}x\inv_{3z}^{xy^2}\pushforward\end{equation}

\begin{equation}x_{3z}\inv\pushforward^{xy^2}\end{equation}

\begin{equation}x_{3z}\pushforward\inv^{xy^2}\end{equation}

\begin{equation}x\pushforward_{3z}^{xy^2}\inv\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x'_1\pushforward'_2\pushforward'_3\pushforward'
\end{equation}

\[
  a'\inv \quad x^2^3_2_{222}^{423}
\]
\endsubsup
\end{document}
```

[image]

As David point out in a comment to the OP, the above method does not support the non-standard but oft used syntax of `x^\frac12` and `x^\mathrm{y}`.  However, even that could be adapted with suitable redefinitions of `\accumsup` and `\accumsub`.

And just to prove it, here is a version that supports the use of `x^\frac12` and `x^\mathrm{y}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-05-27]

\makeatletter% BUG FIX, REPAIRED IN tokcycle 1.41 2021-06-25
\def\tcpopliteralappto#1{\tcpopliteral\@@tmp\tcappto#1from\@@tmp}
\makeatother

\newcommand\testss[2]{%
  \def\thesups{}%
  \def\thesubs{}%
  \tctestifcatnx ^#1{\accumsup}{%
  \tctestifcatnx _#1{\accumsub}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\contss{%
  \tcpeek\next
  \ifx\inv\next
    \tcpop\discard\tcpush\inv\contss
  \else
    \ifx'\next
      \tcpop\discard\tcpush{\empty\prime}\accumsup
    \else
      \ifx\pushforward\next
        \tcpop\discard\tcpush\pushforward\contss
      \else
        \tctestifcatnx ^\next{\tcpop\discard\accumsup}{%
        \tctestifcatnx _\next{\tcpop\discard\accumsub}{\closess}}% 
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand\closess{%
  \ifx\empty\thesups\else
    \addcytoks{^}\groupedcytoks{\addcytoks[1]{\thesups}}\fi
  \ifx\empty\thesubs\else
    \addcytoks{_}\groupedcytoks{\addcytoks[1]{\thesubs}}\fi
}
\newcommand\accumsup{\tcpeek\next\tcpopappto\thesups\chek{\thesups}\contss}
\newcommand\accumsub{\tcpeek\next\tcpopappto\thesubs\chek{\thesubs}\contss}
\newcommand\chek[1]{\ifx\frac\next\popX{#1}\popX{#1}\else
                    \ifx\mathrm\next\popX{#1}\fi\fi}
\newcommand\popX[1]{\tcpopliteralappto#1}

\tokcycleenvironment\subsup
{\testss{##1}{\addcytoks{##1}}}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\tctestifx{\inv##1}{\tcpush\inv}{%
 \tctestifx{\pushforward##1}{\tcpush\pushforward}{%
 \addcytoks{##1}}}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
\newcommand\inv{^{-1}}
\newcommand\pushforward{_{*}}

\begin{document}
\subsup
\[ x\inv^3_2_{22^22}^{423}^\frac12_\mathrm{xy}\pushforward \]
\endsubsup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It still cannot brew coffee. Could you please update it with this change? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Haha!  I presented it in three stages, so that the reader would not be immediately overwhelmed by version 3.  The stages help show the process of increasing complexity.  But, I need to know...is brewing coffee expandable?

Comment: @Gaussler And to top off the irony, the reason I was 13 minutes delayed in responding to your comment was that I was... you guessed it...brewing coffee, which I only do maybe once a week.  Great minds think alike!!

Comment: @Gaussler I'm trying to get readers to comprehend that `tokcycle` is a package for building your own token-processing tools.

Comment: Yes, I see that you like to market `tokcycle` in here a lot. Can’t blame you – I like to market `semantex` a lot. I should probably open your package one of these days to figure out exactly what the concept of it is.

Comment: Your solution requires adjustment for each command such as `\inv`, but I guess there is no avoiding that, so you are getting the bounty. Congratulations. I hope your coffee was great. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler I will continue to seek a way to examine, at least, the first expansion, so that macros whose replacement text begins with `_` or `^` are trapped.  That would be more useful than the current answer.  And thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this quite some time ago. I wrote a command `\@stickysup` that would allow me (after making `^` and `\let`ing it equal to that command) to write `a^1^2^3_4` and get

[image: example output]

(In practice I would have used it only in specific macros instead of replacing the meaning of `^`.)

Since I needed to use a lot of tensor notation for my classes back then, I went a step further and implemented a command that let me write `a^1^2^3_4^5_6_7` and get

[image: example output]

I am posting the relevant code below for your examination. I make no guarantee that this is safe in all circumstances and I have not looked at this code in quite some time so I hope there are not detailed questions about it ;-). The basic idea is the same as for `'` from plain TeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% A sticky superscript command (several of these can follow each other).
\makeatletter
  \def\@stickysup#1{^\bgroup#1\@stickysup@glue}
  \def\@stickysup@glue{\futurelet\@let@token\@stickysup@react}
  \def\@stickysup@react{%
    \ifx\@stickysup\@let@token
      \expandafter\@stickysup@mergestickysup
    \else
      \ifx^\@let@token
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@stickysup@mergesup
      \else
        \ifx'\@let@token
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@stickysup@mergeprime
        \else
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@stickysup@end
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  }
  \def\@stickysup@mergestickysup#1#2{#2\@stickysup@glue}
  \def\@stickysup@mergesup#1#2{#2\egroup}
  \def\@stickysup@mergeprime#1{\prime\@stickysup@glue}
  \def\@stickysup@end{\egroup}
  {\catcode`'\active\gdef'{\@stickysup\prime}}
\makeatother

% add switches for switching between normal and tensor-like sub- and superscripts
% \tensorscripts[<base>] switches on, \notensorscripts switches off.
% \tensor{<base>}{<scripts>} typesets only one tensor (like the {tensor} package)
% \tens{<base>} typesets only one tensor, but without braces around the scripts.
% \notens turns tensorscripts off for one time, but leaves scripts sticky.
% \crippletensorscripts makes _ and ^ not active, but doesn't revert any of the other changes
%   (for use when a \label contains _).
\makeatletter
  \NewDocumentCommand\tensorscripts{O{}}{%
    \let\@sub_\let\@sup^%
    \def\@tensorscript@separator{{\vphantom{#1}}}%
    \catcode`_=\active\catcode`^=\active
    \@tensorscript@activation
  }
  {\catcode`_=\active\catcode`^=\active
    \gdef\@tensorscript@activation{%
      \let_\@tensorsub
      \let^\@tensorsup
      \let\@stickysup@end\@tensorscript@end
    }%
  }
  \def\crippletensorscripts{%
    \catcode`_=8\catcode`^=7%
  }
  
  \def\tensor#1{\begingroup\tensorscripts[#1]#1\@tensor@secondarg}
  \def\@tensor@secondarg#1{#1\endgroup}
  \def\tens#1{\begingroup\tensorscripts[#1]\def\@tensorscript@veryend{\endgroup}#1}
  \def\notens{\begingroup\tensorscripts\def\@tensorscript@separator{\unskip}\def\@tensorscript@veryend{\endgroup}}
  
  \def\@add@tensorscriptcmd#1{%
    \expandafter\def\csname @tensor#1\endcsname##1{%
      \csname @#1\endcsname
      \bgroup
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\@current@tensorscript@cmd\csname @tensor#1\endcsname
      ##1%
      \@tensorscript@glue
    }%
  }
  \@add@tensorscriptcmd{sub}
  \@add@tensorscriptcmd{sup}
  
  \def\@tensorscript@glue{\futurelet\@tensorscript@lettoken\@tensorscript@react}
  \def\@tensorscript@react{%
    \ifx\@current@tensorscript@cmd\@tensorscript@lettoken
      \expandafter\@tensorscript@merge
    \else
      \expandafter\@tensorscript@end
    \fi
  }
  \def\@tensorscript@merge#1#2{#2\@tensorscript@glue}
  \def\@tensorscript@end{\egroup\futurelet\@tensorscript@lettoken\@tensorscript@separate}
  \def\@tensorscript@separate{%
    \ifx\@tensorsub\@tensorscript@lettoken
      \!\@tensorscript@separator
    \else
      \ifx\@tensorsup\@tensorscript@lettoken
        \@tensorscript@separator
      \else
        \@tensorscript@veryend
      \fi
    \fi
  }
  \def\@tensorscript@veryend{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup\makeatletter
  \catcode`^=\active
  \let^\@stickysup
  \[
    a^1^2^3_4
  \]
\endgroup

\[
  \tensorscripts
  a^1^2^3_4^5_6_7
\]

\end{document}
```