# Failing with TeX expansion

Tags: macros, expansion, definition

I'm trying to achieve a (seemingly simple) thing. I'd like to define a custom command `\Symbol` that receives a single parameter and prints that parameter. In addition, I'd like to have another series of commands that modifies the output of `\Symbol`, namely `\PutSymbolSubscript`, `\PutSymbolSuperscript` and `\PutSymbolModifier`. What I'd like to achieve is that one can nest styling of the symbol arbitrarily. For example, I may then define a global symbol as

```
\newcommand{\VectorI}{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{\boldsymbol{x}}}{i}}
```

Furthermore, I can define annother global style

```
\newcommand{\estimate}{\hat}
```

Then I can combine both by writing `\estimate{\VectorI}`, which should render as `\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}_i`.

What I have so far is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% the "Symbol" framework --------------------------------
\newcommand{\Symbol}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\symbolmodifier%
        \let\tmp\symbolmodifier%
        \let\symbolmodifier\undefined%
        \tmp{#1}%
    \else%
        #1%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\symbolsubscript%
        \let\tmp\symbolsubscript
        \let\symbolsubsript\undefined
        _{\tmp}%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\symbolsuperscript%
        \let\tmp\symbolsuperscript%
        \let\symbolsuperscript\undefined%
        ^{\tmp}%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSubscript}[2]{{%
    \newcommand{\symbolsubscript}{#2}       % (C1)
    #1
}}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSuperscript}[2]{{%
    \newcommand{\symbolsuperscript}{#2}     % (C2)
    #1
}}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolModifier}[2]{{%
    \let\symbolmodifier#2
    #1
}}

% some global definitions --------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\PutSampleIdx}[2]{\PutSymbolSuperscript{#1}{(#2)}}
\newcommand{\NTrainSamples}{N}
\newcommand{\estimate}[1]{\PutSymbolModifier{#1}{\hat}}

% test it ----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{A}}{i}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSuperscript{\Symbol{B}}{(2)}\Symbol{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \estimate{\Symbol{C}}\Symbol{D}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSampleIdx{a}{1}
\end{equation}

%\begin{equation}
%    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{\Symbol{N}}
%\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

All of those cases work as expected, except for the last one (commented out), which fails with a `TeX capacity exceeded`. Although I did not really find out why it fails, I noticed that I can solve this issue by replacing the `\newcommand` with a corresponding `\edef` in the lines marked with `(C1)` and `(C2)`. However, even with that, the following fails:

```
\PutSymbolSubscript{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{\Symbol{N}}}{\Symbol{M}}
```

Here, I assert that the outer `\PutSymbolSuperscripts` superseeds the inner one, such that this should render as `X_M`.

In a more complex document, I even get `inaccessible` errors. However, those cases are hard to reproduce with a MWE.

Can anybody help me with implementing this little "symbol framework" correctly?

In case you're wondering why I want to do this: I would like to define symbols globally, such that I can change them lateron. However, symbols may have many variants (with different indices and modifiers) and defining all variants globally is messy. On the other hand, a simple modular approach by for example defining `\newcommand{\estimate}{\hat}` and `\newcommand{\VectorI}{x_i}` and the using it as `\estimate{\VectorI}` produces `\hat{x_i}` which is obviously not what I want to have. Hence, I'd like to do it in such a modular way.. I think this should be possible, right?

Comment: `\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{\noexpand\Symbol{N}}`?  Thus, alternatively (maybe), `\newcommand{\PutSymbolSubscript}[2]{{\newcommand{\symbolsubscript}{\noexpand#2}#1}}`?

Comment: you are defining these as once-only modifiers? `\let\symbolmodifier\undefined%` means that after you print the symbol once using the modifier then next time it will be unmodified?

Comment: In what way is this definition any different from `\newcommand{\PutSymbolSubscript}[2]{#1_{#2}}`  there does not seem to be any possibility of the internal `\symbolsubscript` command having any other effect? similary the other cases.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes, the latter one really helped, thanks! However: I still do not get what is happening under the hood and why the original solution crashes.. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I agree, but this is intentionally.. After investigating your answer below, I realized that the extra curly braces are not helpful at all. However, after removing them, `\PutSymbolSuperscript{\Symbol{A}}{2}\Symbol{B}` renders as `A^2B^2`, which is not intended. So the Symbol needs to "consume" those modifiers. Maybe there is a more elegant way to do so. However, in this situation, it helped..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: When it is about the difference to using for example `\newcommand{\PutSymbolSubscript}[2]{#1_{#2}}`: My approach differs, since it always renders the "modifiers" in the correct order. For example `\estimate{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{Y}}{i}}` would still render as `\hat{Y}_i` and not `\hat{Y_i}`.

Comment: `\Symbol` becomes self-referential without the `\noexpand`, causing an infinite loop.  But even with it, I'm not sure it does what you want, even though it avoids the overflow.

Comment: How are your commands `\PutSymbolSubscript` and `\PutSymbolSuperscript` and `\PutSymbolModifier` supposed to behave in case their 1st argument does not contain the command `\Symbol`?  How are  `\PutSymbolSubscript` and `\PutSymbolSuperscript`  supposed to behave in case of being nested within their 1st argument?

Comment: How is `\PutSymbolModifier{\Symbol{A} bla \Symbol{B}}{\hat}` supposed to behave? Are both `A` and `B` supposed to have a `\hat`?   How is `\PutSymbolModifier{\Symbol{A} bla \PutSymbolModifier{\Symbol{B}}{\tah}}{\hat}` supposed to behave? Is `B` supposed to have both `\hat` and `\tah`? If so: In which order?

Answer (score 3):

The package [`semantex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex) (disclaimer: I am the author) does a lot of the things you want, though with a keyval-based interface instead. It also allows arbitrary nesting. In the below code sample, I have tried to replicated the behaviour I *think* you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,semantex}

\NewVariableClass\MyVar[
    output=\MyVar,
    define keys={
        {estimate}{ command=\hat },
    },
    define keys[1]={
        {der}{ upper={(#1)} },
        %in case ^{(2)} means derived 2 times
    },
]

\NewObject\MyVar\vA{A}
\NewObject\MyVar\vB{B}
\NewObject\MyVar\vC{C}
\NewObject\MyVar\vD{D}
\NewObject\MyVar\vX{X}
\NewObject\MyVar\vN{N}
\NewObject\MyVar\va{a}
\NewObject\MyVar\vi{i}

\NewObject\MyVar\vectorI{\boldsymbol{x}}[lower=\vi]

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \vA[\vi]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \vB[der=2] \vC
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \vC[estimate] \vD
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \va[1]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \vX[\vN]
\end{equation}

Nesting arbitrarily:

\begin{equation}
    \vectorI[estimate,der=5,der=3]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really want to stick to your current syntax, you can do the following instead.
If you really want nested `PutSymbolSubscript`’s to override previous ones, you can replace `upper={#2}` by `data set={upper}{#2}` and `lower={#2}` by `data set={lower}{#2}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,semantex}

\NewVariableClass\Symbol[
    output=\Symbol,
]

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSubscript}[2]{{%
    \Symbol{#1}[lower={#2}]%
}}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSuperscript}[2]{{%
    \Symbol{#1}[upper={#2}]%
}}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolModifier}[2]{{%
    \Symbol{#1}[command={#2}]%
}}

% some global definitions --------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\PutSampleIdx}[2]{\PutSymbolSuperscript{#1}{(#2)}}
\newcommand{\NTrainSamples}{N}
\newcommand{\estimate}[1]{\PutSymbolModifier{#1}{\hat}}

% test it ----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{A}}{i}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSuperscript{\Symbol{B}}{(2)}\Symbol{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \estimate{\Symbol{C}}\Symbol{D}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSampleIdx{a}{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{\Symbol{N}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll have a look at this for later works. However, for this work I don't want to change my syntax..

Comment: @ma0ho Like it better now?

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of `\Symbol` contains a typo:

```
\newcommand{\Symbol}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\symbolmodifier%
        \let\tmp\symbolmodifier%
        \let\symbolmodifier\undefined%
        \tmp{#1}%
    \else%
        #1%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\symbolsubscript%
        \let\tmp\symbolsubscript
        \let\symbolsubsript\undefined
        _{\tmp}%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\symbolsuperscript%
        \let\tmp\symbolsuperscript%
        \let\symbolsuperscript\undefined%
        ^{\tmp}%
    \fi%
}
```

There is the line: `\let\symbolsubsript\undefined`

Just a single small letter `c` is missing.

It should be: `\let\symbolsubscript\undefined`

Thus the definition should be:

```
\newcommand{\Symbol}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\symbolmodifier
        \let\tmp\symbolmodifier
        \let\symbolmodifier\undefined
        \tmp{#1}%
    \else
        #1%
    \fi
    \ifdefined\symbolsubscript
        \let\tmp\symbolsubscript
        \let\symbolsubscript\undefined % <--- !!!!!
        _{\tmp}%
    \fi
    \ifdefined\symbolsuperscript
        \let\tmp\symbolsuperscript
        \let\symbolsuperscript\undefined
        ^{\tmp}%
    \fi
}
```

With that slight modification the sequence

```
\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{\Symbol{N}}
\end{equation}
```

doesn't yield a loop ending in a `capacity exceeded`-error.

---

---

Let's add another approach, based on exchanging arguments instead of defining `\tmp`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Paraphernalia -------------------------------------------
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\firstofone[1]{#1}%

% the "Symbol" framework --------------------------------
\newcommand*\symbolsubscript{}%
\newcommand*\symbolsubscriptdefault{}%
\newcommand*\symbolsuperscript{}%
\newcommand*\symbolsuperscriptdefault{}%
\newcommand*\symbolmodifier{\firstofone}%
\newcommand*\symbolmodifierdefault{\firstofone}%

\newcommand{\Symbol}[1]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\symbolsuperscript}{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\symbolsubscript}{%
      \ifx\symbolsubscript\symbolsubscriptdefault
        \ifx\symbolsuperscript\symbolsuperscriptdefault
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\firstofone
        \else
          \global\let\symbolsuperscript\symbolsuperscriptdefault
        \fi
      \else
        \global\let\symbolsubscript\symbolsubscriptdefault
        \ifx\symbolsuperscript\symbolsuperscriptdefault\else
          \global\let\symbolsuperscript\symbolsuperscriptdefault
        \fi
      \fi
      {%
        \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\symbolmodifier}{%
          \ifx\symbolmodifier\symbolmodifierdefault\else
            \global\let\symbolmodifier\symbolmodifierdefault
          \fi
        }%
        {#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSubscript}[2]{%
  \ifx\symbolsubscript\symbolsubscriptdefault
    \xdef\symbolsubscript{\unexpanded{_{#2}}}%
  \fi
  #1%
}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSuperscript}[2]{%
  \ifx\symbolsuperscript\symbolsuperscriptdefault
    \xdef\symbolsuperscript{\unexpanded{^{#2}}}%
  \fi
  #1%
}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolModifier}[2]{%
    \ifx\symbolmodifier\symbolmodifierdefault
       \xdef\symbolmodifier{\unexpanded{#2}}%
    \fi
    #1%
}

% some global definitions --------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\PutSampleIdx}[2]{\PutSymbolSuperscript{#1}{(#2)}}
\newcommand{\NTrainSamples}{N}
\newcommand{\estimate}[1]{\PutSymbolModifier{#1}{\hat}}
\newcommand{\VectorI}{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{\boldsymbol{x}}}{i}}

% test it ----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{A}}{i}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSuperscript{\Symbol{B}}{(2)}\Symbol{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSuperscript{\estimate{\Symbol{C}}}{2}\Symbol{D}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSampleIdx{\Symbol{a}}{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{\Symbol{N}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{M}}{\Symbol{N}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\PutSymbolSuperscript{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{V}}{\Symbol{M}}}{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSuperscript{\Symbol{X}}{M}
\end{equation}


\[\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}_i\]

\[\estimate{\VectorI}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's rather hard to guess the intent here so I will just comment on

```
\PutSymbolSubscript{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{\Symbol{N}}}{\Symbol{M}}
```

> Here, I assert that the outer `\PutSymbolSuperscripts` superseeds the inner one, such that this should render as `X_M`.

The outer call isn't used at all.

You have

```
\newcommand{\PutSymbolSuperscript}[2]{{%
    \newcommand{\symbolsuperscript}{#2}     % (C2)
    #1
}}
```

so the quoted call is, after one expansion

```
{%
    \newcommand{\symbolsuperscript}{\Symbol{M}}     % (C2)
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}
}
```

so this starts a group from the `{` and defines `\symbolsuperscript` to be M, but the next expansion produces

```
{%
    \newcommand{\symbolsuperscript}{\Symbol{M}}     % (C2)
    {%
       \newcommand{\symbolsuperscript}{\Symbol{N}}     % (C2)
        \Symbol{X}
    }
}
```

So the first definition, to M is never used, it is replaced by the inner definition to N

Perhaps you want to use `\providecommand` not `\newcommand` so that the inner calls only define your modifiers if they are not already defined, but to be honest it's hard to guess the intended behaviour here.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped. I recognized that the additional curly braces do not make sense here. And `\providecommand` gives the intended behaviour (render the most outer modifier).

Comment: @ma0ho you need the curly braces (even though they affect spacing) otherwise your definitions will leak.   You don't want `\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{Y}}{i} \Symbol{X}` to put a subscript on both X and Y

Comment: No, actually this doesn't happen because of the `\let\symbolsubscript\undefined` in the definition of `\Symbol`..

Comment: @ma0ho yes that occurred to me later although I'm not convinced the logic would be right for nested use in that case

Comment: In a certain sense, this whole question of mine boils down to an old complaint of mine: Why are double sub-/superscripts in TeX not stacked? This would make life soooo much easier, and it’s the more natural behaviour.

Comment: @Gaussler no answer to that, just a design choice by Prof. Knuth. I'm not sure that there is any real natural layout for `x^2^3` I assume you want `{x^2}^3`  ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `x^2^3` should be equivalent to `x^{23}`. And [I already asked if this change was possible once before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575108/making-indices-stackable), but not much came out of it.

Comment: @Gaussler oh I'd never have guessed that, seems a strange choice?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hey, I saw your comment before you edited it `:-)`. How can `x^{23}` be anything but the naturally expected behaviour of `x^2^3`?

Comment: @Gaussler because I wouldn't expect that. If I was asked to make x^2^3 a non error I would have made it {x^2}^3. It would not have occured to me to make it x^{23} I was honestly surprised when you suggested that just now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Imagine you take a sheaf `\mathcal{F}` and restrict it to `U` and take the stalk at `p`. Do you want `{\mathcal{F}_{|U}}_{p}`? Probably not. You rather want `\mathcal{F}_{|U,p}`. Double indices are usually stacked, possibly after adding a comma.

Comment: in some cases but I doubt that is the case that lead to the tex decision. The more common usage is `\def\xx{x^2}` ....  `\xx^3`  the intention here is x  squared cubed. You get an error currently, getting {x^2}^3 would be the intended output and getting x^{23} would be mathematically wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This error is what should prompt you to add an extra pair of parentheses around the symbol, i.e. `(\xx)^3`.

Comment: @Gaussler exactly which is why TeX makes it an error to force you to make a decision. making it make x^{23} with no error would not be an improvement at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case, true. But in many other cases, such as my sheaf example above, what you really want is stacked indices. Another example is if you define `\der{#1}{#2}` to be `#1^{(#2}`, i.e. `#1` derived `#2` times. Then `\der{\der{a}{1}}{2}` should naturally yield `a^{(1)(2)}`. Similarly, if `\push{#1}` expands to `#1_{*}` (the pushforward), then `\push{\pi_{1}}` should yield `\pi_{1*}`.

Comment: sure there are cases that need that (the standard macros behind `'` do that already so `x''` is `x^{\prime\prime}`  as you say sometimes you need to use commas, several other variants exist for which macro solutions are not particularly difficult. But I would say the only non-error choice for the primitive x^2^3 would be {x^2}^3  as that is the only version that doesn't risk being mathematically completely wrong rather than just typographically inelegant.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But is it wrong to want a macro for pushforwards? Please define a command `\push` for pushforwards, and then please make it work on the macro `\projone` which is defined to be `\pi_{1}` (the projection onto the first component). Take as much time as you want. There are only two options: (1) Making subscripts stackable, or (2) a `semantex`-style solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126805/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-gaussler).

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing many of the hints, I finally arrived at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% the "Symbol" framework --------------------------------
\newcommand{\Symbol}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\symbolmodifier%
        \let\tmp\symbolmodifier%
        \let\symbolmodifier\undefined%
        \tmp{#1}%
    \else%
        #1%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\symbolsubscript%
        \let\tmp\symbolsubscript
        \let\symbolsubscript\undefined
        _{\tmp}%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\symbolsuperscript%
        \let\tmp\symbolsuperscript%
        \let\symbolsuperscript\undefined%
        ^{\tmp}%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSubscript}[2]{%
    \providecommand{\symbolsubscript}{#2}
    #1
}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolSuperscript}[2]{%
    \providecommand{\symbolsuperscript}{#2}
    #1
}

\newcommand{\PutSymbolModifier}[2]{%
    \let\symbolmodifier#2
    #1
}

% some global definitions --------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\PutSampleIdx}[2]{\PutSymbolSuperscript{#1}{(#2)}}
\newcommand{\NTrainSamples}{N}
\newcommand{\estimate}[1]{\PutSymbolModifier{#1}{\hat}}

% test it ----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{A}}{i}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSuperscript{\Symbol{B}}{(2)}\Symbol{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSuperscript{\estimate{\Symbol{C}}}{2}\Symbol{D}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSampleIdx{\Symbol{a}}{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \PutSymbolSubscript{\PutSymbolSubscript{\Symbol{X}}{M}}{\Symbol{N}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which works well for all the given cases..

Comment: @UlrichDiez: Maybe I was a bit to fast here and you're right that exponent in (4) was missing. Also the "c" in `\let\symbolsubsript\undefined` was missing. Both are fixed now. However, in Eq. (5), this is intended behavior. Here, only the most outer `\PutSymbolSubscript` is taken into consideration. To me, this absolutely makes sense, since it allows to override previous (possibly global) definitions at any time..